# Can't chop last X letters from a string

Tags: bash

I'm on a mac, bash version 5.0.2.

Got this:

```
    v="ksdjfksjkjsdf"
    v2=${v::-6}
```

Get this:

```
-bash: -6: substring expression < 0
```

Comment: Which version of `bash`? I just tried this with 4.4.12 and it worked as expected.

Comment: at the top of the post: 5.0.2

Comment: Are you sure you are providing us with the exact variables you are working with?  It seems the way you get this error is trying to trim more characters from a string than exist.   Your example should never fail but if you tried `v2=${v::-14}` it would

Comment: Positive. Yes. That's all I have in my test script besides shebang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are running the script with the correct bash version? Is your shebang line ok? How about calling the script with `bash myscript.sh?`

Comment: Turns out my `bash --version` returns different value than `/bin/bash --version`. OP was running with `#!/bin/bash` version.

Answer (score 6):

[Using negative lengths was added in Bash 4.2](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges):

> ${PARAMETER:OFFSET:LENGTH}: Negative LENGTH values are used as offset from the end of the string  4.2-alpha

And it seems to work for me with Bash versions 4.2.53, 4.4.12 and 5.0.3. With any of those, I get:

```
$ s=123456; echo "${s::-2}"
1234
$ s=123456; echo "${s::-8}"
bash: -8: substring expression < 0
```

That is, it works as long as the absolute value of the negative length isn't greater than the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
v="aksdjfkajsdkfjakdf"
length=${#v}
v2=${v:0: length - 6}
```

Comment: This will not work if the length of `v` is less than 6 characters, which is likely your issue in the first place.

Comment: I know it's more than 6 characters in the code it will be used in.

Comment: Why are you downvoting the correct answer? I just ran it. In this example I have a string way more than 6 characters.

Comment: You should file a bug report with bash

Comment: I have no idea if it's a bug or not. Could work differently in bash 5.

Comment: I'm using 5.0.2 in OSX and I cannot reproduce your results without trying to subtract more than the length of the string

Comment: In the first example in the OP, I clearly have more than 6 characters there.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Doesn't work for me. Using homebrew version.

Comment: OK, so, when I do /bin/bash  --version I get version 3.2.57. When I do bash --version on the command line, I get version 5.0.2. So this is the issue. So somehow my install is hosed or I am not understanding how bash gets loaded when I fire up a new terminal window.

Comment: It worked great for me. I Know I wanted to truncate only the last character and I know the input string is always greater than 1 character. So I don't see an issue accepting this answer under these circumstances. Thanks @StevieD

Answer (score -1):

I have done by below method

```
v="ksdjfksjkjsdf"
echo $v| awk -F "" '{gsub("","\n",$0);print $0}'| sed '/^$/d'| sed -n '1,7p'| perl -pne g"/\n//g"
```

output

```
 echo $v| awk -F "" '{gsub("","\n",$0);print $0}'| sed '/^$/d'| sed -n '1,7p'| perl -pne g"/\n//g"

ksdjfks
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? I get each character on a separate line. In any case, you can do all this in a single AWK invocation, or `sed`, or Perl, there’s no need to run multiple programs. (As a general rule of thumb, if you’re using Perl, you don’t need AWK; if you’re using AWK, you don’t need `sed`.)